# Getting relative inner class name in Java

Tags: java, reflection

```
package u.v;

class x {
    static class xx {
        static class xxx { }
    }
}
```

While I can get the canonical ("absolute") name of the inner class

```
public class a{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(x.xx.xxx.class.getCanonicalName());   //u.v.x.xx.xxx
    }
}
```

and I can also get the last component of the class name

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(x.xx.xxx.class.getSimpleName());   //xxx
    }
```

how would I go around elegantly getting a relative class name?

```
Utils.relativeClassName(x.xx.xxx.class, x.class);   //xx.xxx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function. The `+1` is for the extra `.`

```
public static String getRelativeClassName(Class<?> inner, Class<?> outer) {
  int length = outer.getCanonicalName().length();
  return inner.getCanonicalName().substring(length+1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The following string manipulation should do the job:
`xxx.class.getCanonicalName().substring(x.class.getCanonicalName().length + 1)`

`+1` is for `.` (dot) between the last outer class name and the name of interesting class.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder me too, obviously ;)

Comment: @durron597: Best to delete duplicates.